# Why is the penis, a male organ, "阴茎"?

Tags: etymology

The penis is translated as "阴茎" (literally "yin stem"), but it is a male organ. In the [traditional concepts of yin and yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang#Meanings), "阴" is generally associated with the female sex.

To support the idea, the term ["阳具"](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E9%99%BD%E5%85%B7) (literally "yang tool") is also used to describe the penis (and scrotum).

Why is the penis, a male reproductive organ, associated with the word "阴"?

Answer (score 3):

According [to this fengshui expert](http://fengshuichina.blog.sohu.com/93463692.html), the penis and the vagina are both named not because of the gender of the bearer, but via Western medical terminology because they originate from the perineum [(会阴)](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%83%E9%99%B0).

> “阴茎”这个称呼不是中国人发明的。它属于从西方医学中翻译过来的外来语，与我们中国的阴阳学说无关。从解剖学角度来讲，耻骨至肛门之前的区域叫会阴区。在这个区域的内在“通道”称作“阴道”，外在如茎之物称作“阴茎”，想一想也是很形象的。而以阴阳学说为基础的中国古典医学并不把男性生殖器叫阴茎，而是称为阳根、阳具或者阳物。

Answer (score 2):

或者说在传统的观念里，头为阳，越往下即为阴。凑字数凑字数，凑字数。

阴是医学叫法，指的是平时遮住的地方。阳是传统叫法。

因为生殖器官所在的位置叫下阴，生殖器官中的“阴”和男女的“阴阳”是不能作对比的。

Comment: Do you think this could be be because 阴 suggests "hidden"?  Or somehow covered over?

Comment: 那么为什么男性的那个位置被称为下阴呢？下阳不会更合适吗？Then why is that place called 下阴, even though it's a place in the male body? Wouldn't 下阳 be more appropriate? :)

Comment: @ColinMcLarty I believe it's "dark" so "covered/shaded" is close. 阴，暗也。——《说文》

Comment: -1, no sources made to support this argument.

Comment: @Sweeper 这又不是我定的，我也很无奈啊.....

Comment: I.......cannot explain it

Comment: +1 for the answer below (医学叫法)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Chinese boy is right, 陰 is a technical term for the genitals, male or female.

Etymologically, 陰 as genitals may very well have come from dark, hidden, etc. as Colin suggested above. Morohashi's Dai kanwa jiten cites 釋名, a late Han dynasty dictionary, for this meaning: 陰，蔭也。言所在蔭翳也。 Not so different from English 'privates' perhaps.

Examples of 陰 without regard to male or female include 陰部 'genitals', 外陰 'external genitalia', 陰毛 'pubic hair', 陰蝨 'crabs' and so on. Other male body parts using 陰 include 陰囊 'scrotum'.